# Minimizing the probability of a Guassian random variables to be positive

Tags: probability-theory, matrix-calculus, gaussian

Suppose that $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu(M),\sigma^2(M))$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R} $ and $\sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}_+$ are functions of its matrix-valued argument $M$. I found in [this manuscript](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2007/file/9f61408e3afb633e50cdf1b20de6f466-Paper.pdf) that the matrix $M^∗$ which minimizes the probability of $X$ to be positive is given by $$ M^* = \mathrm{argmin}_{M} \frac{\mu(M)}{\sigma^2(M)}$$  May I know how to derive this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, it seems you are asking for the value of $M$ to minimize $P(\sigma(M) Z + \mu (M)> 0)$? Well, then rearranging, we get $P(Z > -\mu(M) /\sigma(M)) =: F(-\mu(M)/\sigma(M))$, which is of course a monotone function in its argument, since it is a complementary CDF. So, the result you have (correctly) cited seems to miss a square root?

Comment: Nope... The goal is not to find $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to minimize $\mathbb P(\sigma Z + \mu) > 0$, but to find the "parameter" $M$ that minimizes this probability, here $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are functions of the parameter $M$... But I think your reasoning is acceptable...

Comment: Yes, I meant your goal should be to minimize the ratio $\mu/\sigma$ as per the proof above? Let me make the dependence on $M$ more explicit.

Comment: Thank you... This might mean that the paper is wrong....lol...

Comment: I just checked your profile and it seems it is not the first time you caught a bug in a machine learning paper :D https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271692/a-possible-bug-in-a-highly-cited-paper-adam-gradient-descent

Comment: lol this, but that bug has been addressed in many research papers, which means it is easy to spot such a bug